# Різниця між додатком і обставиною

Tags: граматика, означення

#### Додаток

[Додатком](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA_(%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE)) (у лінгвістиці) називають член речення, що показує об'єкт, на який спрямова дія. Додаток може бути:

- *прямим* — стоїть у знахідному відмінку без прийменників:

  > Я побачив *дівчину*.
  >   Я кидаю *м'яч*.

  Також іноді прямий додаток стояти бути в родовому відмінку (в т. ч. у запереченнях):

  > Я не люблю *ненависті*.
- *непрямим* — стоїть у іншому відмінку (окрім називного — другорядні члени речення рідко бувають у називному відмінку) або з використанням прийменника:

  > Я малюю *олівцем*.
  >   Я читаю *дитині*.
  >   Я розізлився *на дружину*.
  >   Він суворий *до себе*.
  >   Він думає *про інших*.
- *іншим* — виражений не іменною частиною мови:

  > Я прошу *пробачити* ¹.

  <sup>¹ Примітка: в даному випадку «пробачити» не можна вважати частиною сладного [присудка](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA), бо дія «пробачити» стосується не суб'єкта («я»), а іншої особи (в реченні «Іван ***хоче*** пробачити» оте «пробачити» іноді інтерпретують як частину складного присудка, бо і хоче, і пробачає Іван).</sup>

#### Обставина

[Обставиною](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0_(%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE)) (у лінгвістиці) називають член речення, що показує ознаку/характеристику дії. Виділяють обставини місця, часу, способу, причини, мети, умови, допустовості, міри.

> Я летів *з дому / в небі / на північ*.
>   Я приїду *через рік*.
>   Я приїду *поїздом*.
>   Я повстав *через переконання*.
>   Я повстав *задля справедливості*.
>   Я прийду *за можливості*.
>   Я вийшов *всупереч дощу*.
>   Я втомився *до краю*.

#### То в чому моє питання?

В тому, що більшість наведених вище обставин виражаються іменниками у непрямих відмінках. Як зрозуміти, коли іменники у непрямих відмінках (можливо, з прийменниками) є додатками, а коли — обставинами?

Он [підручник до ЗНО](http://zno.academia.in.ua/mod/book/view.php?id=1383) та [підручник 5 класу](http://edufuture.biz/index.php?title=%D0%94%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%96_%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F:_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA,_%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F,_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0._%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8_%D1%97%D1%85_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8) кажуть про додаток:

> означає предмет
>   відповідає на питання кого? чого? кому? чому? кого? що? ким? чим? на кому? на чому?

То у «я мешкаю на Борщагівці» оте «на Борщагівці» — це все таки додаток чи обставина? Як визначити?

<sub>P. S.: Мені здається, я знаю відповідь. Але вона виглядає доволі нестандартно і не підтведжується жодними джерелами, тож, можливо, є нісенітницею. Тому хочу почути «канонічні» думки щодо цього питання (або просто інші).</sub>

Comment: Розділення на додаток та обставину застаріле. Фактично і той, і той є частинами присудку, the verb phrase. Реально виокремити можна лише іменники в знахідному відмінку без прийменника – це прямі додатки. Непрямі додатки від обставин відрізнити проблематично.

Comment: @YellowSky, джерело і що саме придумали на заміну? (Те, що за семантикою вони є частинами присудка, й так зрозуміло. Але ж оці частини присудка мають якусь класифікацію?)

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not qualified enough to answer those questions. Read a modern book on syntax, that's all. The most advanced modern syntax theory is called "[X-bar theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-bar_theory)".

Comment: @YellowSky, I supposed you can advice some simple readings about the replacement (if it's really a replacement and is widely adopted). OK, I'll try to read about X-bar theory (though I'm not sure whether it's a fully drop-in replacement or no). Anyway, the question "what does classic theory think about it?" (especially "local Ukrainian linguistics", as it can differ from the Russian or from the world-wide one) remains.

Answer (score 1):

Згідно з ["Практикумом з правопису і граматики української мови"](http://osvita-center.com.ua/catalog/5-klas/yushchuk-i-p-praktikum-z-pravopisu-i-gramatiki-ukrainskoy-movi-posibnik-isbn-978-617-656-160-6-/), ст. 202, член речення може бути  **одночасно обставиною та додатком** залежно від того, яке питання поставити:

Я мешкаю (де?) на Борщагівці. - обставина.
Я мешкаю (на чому?) на Борщагівці. - додаток.

Але ж ви не питатимете "На чому ти мешкаєш?" тому переважно вважається обставиною.

Про канонічність наведеного підручника:

> Схвалено для використання у загальноосвітніх навчальних закладах комісією з української мови Науково-методичної ради з питань освіти Міністерства освіти і науки, молоді та спорту України (лист Інститут інноваційних технологій і змісту освіти від 28.05.2012 р. №Г-107)

Ознайомитися з електронною версією підручника можна [тут](http://educrimea.org/lib/books/Yushchuk.pdf), тільки у наведеному pdf - 199 сторінка, читайте "Та це ж просто".

П.С. На жаль, у мене з граматикою не дуже, це єдиний підручник з граматики, який я читав, і що про це думають на ЗНО - гадки не маю. Проте вирішив, що краще така відповідь, ніж жодної відповіді )

Comment: Але ж 5-й клас! Вам не видається, що в 5-му класі можуть трішки спрощено лінгвістику вчити (як і інші дисципліни)? Тим більше, що в підручнику: «Я  зрозумів:  усе  залежить  від  конкретного  змісту,  закладеного  в реченні.» Тобто не сказано, що кожна така штука в кожному реченні є одночасно і додатком, і обставиною, а сказано, що саме «з-за лісу» (без указання контексту) може бути і тим, і тим — а далі вирішує контекст. І як же він вирішує? Але дякую!

Comment: @Sasha Так ліпше? :) http://osvita-center.com.ua/catalog/11-klas/yushchuk-i-p-praktikum-z-pravopisu-i-gramatiki-ukrainskoy-movi-posibnik-isbn-978-617-656-160-6-/

Comment: @Sasha Трохи більш серйозно: у каталозі цей підручник там є від 5 до 11 класу (у всіх класах). З опису: "Посібник може бути використаний учителем для організації індивідуальної та групової роботи як на уроках, так і вдома, а також для самостійної роботи учнів старших класів, **абітурієнтів, студентів.**". Далі, там чітко написано: питання: "Я  розбираю  речення: 'З-за  лісу  місяць випливає' і  ніяк не  можу визначити, 'з-за лісу' - обставина місця чи додаток?" і відповідь: "І обставина, і додаток. Усе залежить від того, як поставиш питання." Тобто і те, і інше одночасно... (далі буде)

Comment: @Sasha Як на мене, прочитати варшу версію не виходить - питають же про конкретне речення. І написано "залежить від того, як поставиш питання", а не "залежить від конкретного речення". Не переконав? :)

Comment: Ну так там далі написано: «Але мені здається, що *з-за лісу* тут більше обставина, ніж додаток.» І далі: «Я  зрозумів:  усе  залежить  від  конкретного  змісту,  закладеного  в реченні.» Хоча, може, я й переборщив. Але все одно ж це *шкільний* підручник. (Хоча, може, я просто під свою версію підігнати намагаюсь. Або надто звик до математичних дисциплін, де кожен наступний рік навчання — нові відкриття і вточнення, тому те, що у школі казали, не є критерієм істини.)